# При нажатии на кнопку добавлять на страницу компонент Таблицы, React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, map

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку "+Поле" снизу данной таблицы должна появляться еще одна такая же

Вот код таблицы и кнопки :

```
<div>
  <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} showHeader={false} />
</div>
<Button onClick={() => addField()}>+Поле</Button>
```

Вот функция, которую я написала :

```
const addField = () => {
    setAddFieldArray(<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} showHeader={false} />)
    return addFieldArray?.map(elem => elem)
  }
```

Но тут vs code мне выдает следующую ошибку :

"Свойство "map" не существует в типе "boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal".
Свойство "map" не существует в типе "string"."

Как исправить это?

Comment: весь компонент нужно посмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам TS говорит, что вы вызываете метод `map` у типа, в котором данного метода нет.
Вы либо неправильно определили тип `addFieldArray`, либо обращаетесь не к той переменной.

Comment: const [addFieldArray, setAddFieldArray] = useState<React.ReactNode>([])

Comment: У вас useState хранит не массив, а 1 элемент типа React.ReactNode. Если подразумевается, что у вас будет в стейте массив нод, то тип надо указывать <React.ReactNode []> или <Array<React.ReactNode>>

Comment: да, это я тоже пробовала
тогда появляется другая ошибка 
в записи
```
setAddFieldArray(<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} showHeader={false} />)
```
на компонент таблицы : Аргумент типа "Element" нельзя назначить параметру типа "SetStateAction<ReactNode[]>".
  Тип "Element" не может быть назначен для типа "(prevState: ReactNode[]) => ReactNode[]".
    Тип "Element" не предоставляет соответствия для сигнатуры "(prevState: ReactNode[]): ReactNode[]".

Comment: setAddFieldArray должен принимать МАССИВ, члены которого имеют тип React.ReactNode, вы же просто передаете элемент с типом React.ReactNode